# Jackson serialize and wrap attributes into a new Object

Tags: java, json, jackson

Serializing object of the following class yeilds string like

```
public class User implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer pinCode;
    private String city;

    // getters /setters
}

{"id":1,"name":"XYZ","pinCode":123456,"city":"ABC"}
```

But we want that attributes pinCode and city should be a part of new Json node say address node.

So my expectation of the result is:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "XYZ",
  "address": {
    "pinCode": 123456,
    "city": "ABC"
  }
}
```

Can this be accomplished without re-organizing the class structure and by using Json annotations

on the exact opposite lines of @JsonUnwrapped

Answer (score 3):

you can use such workaround(but preferred to use JsonSerialize):

```
public class User implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer pinCode;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String city;

    @JsonProperty("address")
    public Map<String, Object> getAddress() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("pinCode", pinCode);
        map.put("city", city);
        return map;
    }

    //Deserealization
    public void setAddress(Map<String, Object> map) { 
        if(map!=null) { 
            city = (String) map.get("city"); 
            pinCode = (Integer) map.get("pinCode"); 
        } 
    }

    // getters /setters
}
```

Thanks to @hemantvsn for deserialization example

Comment: Getting desired:
{"id":1,"name":"XYZ","address":{"pinCode":411001,"city":"PUNE"}}

Comment: This should work for deserialization too

 public void setAddress(Map<String, Object> map) {
   if(map!=null) {
    city = (String) map.get("city");
    pinCode = (Integer) map.get("pinCode");
   }
  }

Comment: What if we want to document the attributes, using swagger annotations (for example: ApiModelProperty)? I don't think it will be possible ...

Comment: @OmarZRIDI I am not familiar with Swagger, but as far as I can see you're right, the swagger annotations don't provide such ability. I may propose to use _reference_ attribute of the _@ApiModelProperty_ annotation. If it is suitable for you, you may document the attributes in the separate file and include it here

Answer (score -1):

Add another class called `Address` like below:

```
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private Integer pinCode;
    private String city;

    // getters /setters
}
```

Then use `Address` class inside `User` class like below:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    // getters /setters
}
```

Now Jackson give you json string like :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "XYZ",
  "address": {
    "pinCode": 123456,
    "city": "ABC"
  }
}
```

@JsonProperty("address.pinCode") used to set field name in json. Please see doc here for more detail [JsonProperty](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html)

Comment: @JsonUnwrapped - achieves exact opposite effect. Was expecting something on that front

Comment: @hemantvsn - yeah JsonUnwrapped append inner class fields into base class json http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html

Comment: So my need is something that does opposite job of @JsonUnwrapped :P

Comment: But there is no any annotation avaiable in Jackson does actually what you want but you can achieve nested json object using nested class in java model class. Other wise you can develop your processing part during json return where you can able parse your json string as you want. :)